# What to do with leftover crumb topping?

Tags: baking, culinary-uses

After making an [apple crostata](http://www.marthastewart.com/355089/apple-crumb-crostata), I was left with a lot of leftover crumb topping. The topping is delicious and I could eat it by itself ;) But since it includes raw flour, I'd rather find a more sophisticated and easy on my stomach solution. Do any of you have any creative ideas that involve using crumb topping without baking another pastry? :)

The ingredients of my topping are:

- 3/4 cup all-purpose flour
- 1/4 cup packed dark-brown sugar
- 1/4 cup granulated sugar
- 1/2 teaspoon coarse salt
- 1/2 teaspoon cinnamon
- 1/4 teaspoon allspice
- 1 stick cold unsalted butter

I probably have 1/3 left.

Comment: I'd just sprinkle it on fruit. Any combination of apples, pears and peaches would be nice, even if the fruit is canned. Leave the fruit a bit moist, sprinkle on the topping, and bake until the fruit is hot and the topping is toasted.

Answer (score 3):

If you really don't want to bake anything else, you could bake the crumb on it's own. I'd be sure to put it on parchment or a silpat to avoid it sticking to the surface below. Bake it at 350F or so until it's browned. Once it's baked, it should last a while as long as it's stored in an airtight container. It would probably be good as an ice cream topping?

Comment: Excellent. I actually ended up baking a tiny bit of it on its own on parchment next to the crostata, and in the time needed for the crostata to bake it obviously burned. So I will try with lower time and temp (350 instead of 375-400) and won't let if out of my sight ;)

Comment: You could bake it higher, but since the layer will be so thin it won't need much time.

Comment: This is pretty much what I do. Bake it, put it on ice cream or use it to garnish a fancy dessert plate.  It's also good for anchoring a quenelle of ice cream in a plated dessert. One minor tweak: I'd stir the crumble halfway through baking so it's evenly cooked. Turn it over, and move the outside stuff towards the inside of the pan.

Answer (score 0):

That is a pretty generic crumb topping.

You could use it for any purpose:  on top of a coffee cake, muffin, or whatever else.  You could make cobblers or similar in small ramekins to use up the small quantity that you have.

It should also freeze very well, for next time you do make crostada or something similar.

Comment: I like the idea of making mini cobblers. I was just wondering if I could somehow bake the topping alone or with something quick and easy like a meringue (sounds like a crazy combination, but I have leftover egg whites as well ;)). Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: This is also a good use for leftover egg whites, if you have almonds or almond flour on hand (I make mine with huckleberries instead of rhubarb): http://orangette.blogspot.com/2006/05/celebrity-cake.html